# Proof by using sequences $a_n, b_n$ to show that $x_n \notin [a_n, b_n]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[image]

This is how I did (i): [image: Exercise 5 (i)]

(ii) I want to use the previous task to show this one, but I'm not sure how to do it. This is what I have thought so far:
Since $(a_n)$ is increasing, ($b_n$) is decreasing and $(a_n)<(b_n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have that $(a_n)$ is bounded above by $(b_n)$ and $(b_n)$ is bounded below by $(a_n)$. Since they both are bounded and monotone, they will converge to a number in $\mathbb{R}$. From the previous task, we have that:
$$(b_n - a_n)= 1/3 (b_{n-1}-a_{n-1})= 1/{3^n}(b_0-a_0)$$
I don´t know what to do next. Maybe I should prove that $(b_n - a_n)$ goes to $0$? But I don´t know how to argue that $x_n \notin [a_n, b_n]$

Comment: ii) follows easily from i) by induction.

Comment: @geetha290krm Can I use induction with the information I have gotten in (ii)?

Comment: $x_n \notin [a_n,b_n]$ comes automatically when you use induction to construct $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I don´t think I understand what you mean, but thank you anyway :D